# If $f$ is equal to an affine function up to $1$-th order at $a$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$, proof more subtle then it appears?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

I came across the following exercise:

> Two functions $f, g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are **equal up to $n$th order** at $a$ if $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - g(a + h)}{h^n} = 0.
> $$ Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there is a function $g$ of the form $g(x) = a_0 + a_1(x - a)$ such that $f$ and $g$ are equal up to first order at $a$.

For the proof, if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $a_0 := f(a)$ and $a_1 = f'(a)$ fulfill the requirements, this is the easy direction. For the other direction, suppose there exists such an $g(x) = a_0 + a_1(x-a)$, then I found [precisely I found it [here](http://vision.caltech.edu/~kchalupk/spivak.html), it is Problem 2-9] the following solution, on
$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - (a_0 + a_1h)}{h}
$$
add $\lim a_1 = a_1$ to get
$$
 \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - a_0}{h} = a_1.
$$
For $a_0 \ne f(a)$, the limit diverges, so we must have $a_0 = f(a)$, then we get the limit for the derivative, and so $a_1 = f'(a)$. $\square$

But I doubt that
$$
 \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - a_0}{h} < \infty \qquad (*)
$$
implies $a_0 = f(a)$ (if nothing is assumed about $f : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$).

I think everything that follows is that:

1) $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = a_0$

2) $f(a) \to a_0$ faster then any linear term (otherwise the $h$ in the denominator would not be "compensated" and it still diverges)

And so $a_0 = f(a)$ just follows for continuous $f$, where we have $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$?

Am I right? And by the way, conclusion 1) and 2) I just reached by an intuitive feeling, any ideas how to make this precise?

Comment: How did the $h$ in the denominator get bumped to the numerator? It should be $$\frac{1-a_0(a+h)}{h(a+h)}$$ Then you'll see that the limit diverges.

Comment: Yes. You are right, thank you! I removed this example, but my question still remains, and I think this conclusion is just valid in case $f$ is assumed to be continuous at $a$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The occurrence of $h^n$ in the denominator excludes (for $n > 0$) the possibility that $h = 0$ can be part of the limit, hence the limit doesn't say anything about the value of $f$ at $a$, and you need to require continuity in $a$ to obtain differentiability in $a$.

Comment: Guess there are also some subtle points about "speed of convergence" which I cannot make precise, but I found an example which is continuous (yet this is also not enough)! Set $f(x) = \log(x)$ then for each $a_0$ and $a > 0$ we have (by l'Hospital) $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\log(a+h) - a_0}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1/(a+h)}{1} = 1/a.$$ So this limit exists, but it says nothing about $a_0$, because each $a_0$ would work, so I guess we have to suppose continuity at $a$ and also something about the speed of convergence at $a$, but I am unsure how to formulate this precisely...

Comment: You can only apply l'Hospital if the numerator also has limit $0$, so you need $a_0 = \log a$.

Comment: Can you supply a proof (preferable an $\varepsilon-\delta$-proof), I tried on my own, but I hang at the point, and can use that $1/h$ and $f(a+h) - a_0$ get arbitrary small for continuous $f$ at $a$ and $a_0 = f(a)$, but I stuck when I set both these quantities in relation... so would be nice if seeing it proven clearly?

Comment: Or even better, do you know a non-continuous function at $a$ such that $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - a_0}{h} < \infty $$ for some $a_0 \ne f(a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said, the assumptions say nothing about $f(a)$. E.g., the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,\quad & x =0\\
0,\quad & x\ne 0\end{cases}$$
agrees with $g(x)\equiv 0$ up to any order, according to the definition. Yet, it's not differentiable at $0$, since it's not continuous there.

There are three ways to fix this:

1. Add the requirement $f(a)=g(a)$ in the definition of "agree up to order $n$" (this is what I would do).
2. Change the statement to "Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if it is continuous at $a$ and there is a function $g$..."
3. Change the statement to "Show that $f$ can be made  differentiable at $a$ (by redefining $f(a)$ if needed) if and only if there is a function $g$..."

Once the statement is corrected, the exercise should not present any difficulty.